# REST Query based on Expanded columns in multi choice fields (Listdata.svc)

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2010, client-side

I have a SP2010 client side app making REST calls.  I have a large list that I would like to make a filtered query using the value of a none or many choice field called 'displays'. I have no access to add to server side code on this one.

When I 'expand' the query I can access the value of the choice like so

```
myDataVar.d.results[0].Displays.results[0].Value
```

Because dragging 1000 rows to the client to show 20 is cruel and unusual network punishment I need to filter `d.results` on `.Displays.results[0].Value`.

I have tried this:

```
[site]/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/MasterDataList?$filter=Displays/Value eq 'Wide'
```

I am rewarded with the error message

> "No property 'Value' exists in type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]]' at position 9."

Per [another thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14482/how-can-i-filter-based-on-choice-fields-when-using-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-20) I have tried

```
/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/MasterDataList?$filter=DisplaysValue eq 'Wide'&$expand=Displays
```

error:

*No property 'DisplaysValue' exists in type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity' at position 0.*

Testing for 'Displays' without the 'Value' suffix the error is:

*Operator 'eq' incompatible with operand types 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity, Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]]' and 'System.String' at position 9.*

---

My stuck back in 2010 again thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if this is even possible in 2010. I does not help me at all here however, pretty sure this could be done in 2013+.

Comment: To what extent are you stuck with using REST? You'd be able to use a regular ol' CAML query in SharePoint 2010's JavaScript Object Model if that's an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods you are attempting only work with choice columns that are NOT multi-select.  Unfortunately, multi-select choice columns are not supported by the REST interface.  Same holds true for SharePoint 2013 apparently.

FWIW, I ran into this same issue when trying to do the same thing from an Angular JS app within SharePoint.  I ended up creating my own implementation of a multi-value choice field, which then stores the resulting data in JSON format inside of a multi-line text column in SharePoint.  This then allowed me to query that field using REST with no problems.

Comment: This has been the overall consensus. The SAD fact is that using the SOAP interface you could get them. Although you had to parse the ;#nn's ...